# How do I download my database from my android app that uses a SQLite table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

How do I download a copy of a SQLite table that my android app generates?

Comment: You do not need to download it. It is already there in your device. Do you want to change its location? or send it somewhere (server)?

Comment: Yes, how would I create a copy of the database on my Desktop ?

Comment: you can access the file using the path: /data/data/com.example.yourapplicationpackage/databases/products.db and then send it to your server.